# Nstimer Deciseconds

Tags: objective-c

Hey i'm trying to do countdown timer and it seems to work with mm:ss, but im having trouble showing deciseconds, which are 1/10 of a seconds. How can i make it show deciseconds?

example MM:SS:DS (Deciseconds)

```
-(IBAction)start{
myTicker = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(showActivity) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}


- (void)showActivity{

    if (d == 0) {
        [myTicker invalidate];

    } else {

    d = d - 1;

    }    
    int seconds = d % 60;
    int minutes = (d / 60 / 10) % 60;   

    if (d < 10) {

    time.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds];

    } else {

   time.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds];

  }




}
```

Comment: For starters, you have to use a timer with an interval other than 1.0 seconds...

Comment: Yes i know, but if i do that i cant get the seconds to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i believe you want to achieve 10th of a second. so here is a code that does that for you. you should start date/time to keep track of the countdown, Because iOS can delay firing the timer for other tasks.

```
- (void)countdownUpdateMethod:(NSTimer*)theTimer {
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval elaspedTime = [currentDate timeIntervalSinceDate:startTime];

NSTimeInterval difference = countdownSeconds - elaspedTime;
if (difference <= 0) {
    [theTimer invalidate];
    [startTime release];
    difference = 0;
  }
countdownLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Seconds: %.1f", difference];
 }
 - (IBAction)startCountdown {
countdownSeconds = 10;
startTime = [[NSDate date] retain];
countdownLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Seconds: %.1f", countdownSeconds];
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector     (countdownUpdateMethod:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```